How to decrease the time for timed out in Heroku?
Currently, I am running an app in Heroku. It uses several dynos at a time. But the problem is dynos getting stuck. It does not return anything and sits idle for 24 hours and kills itself. I was wondering are there a ways to shorten the time of idle dynos? I was wondering if dynos sits still for an hour, or 30 mins or 2 hours, we want to kill itself. I want to reduce the time from 24 hours to an hour or something like that. Is there a way to do that ?

I think you are in wrong place. Maybe ask Heroku's admins for this,

@furas where to find Heroku's  admins. Is there a community ? I did not find one.

you should find Heroku's admins on Heroku's page - at the bottom of page you have links to support like help center. Eventually you could try to ask on similar portal Server Fault
